# Kubernetes - Pass Public IP of Load Balance as Environment Variable into Pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-kubernetes-engine

## Gist

I have a `ConfigMap` which provides necessary environment variables to my pods:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: global-config
data:
  NODE_ENV: prod
  LEVEL: info

  # I need to set API_URL to the public IP address of the Load Balancer
  API_URL: http://<SOME IP>:3000

  DATABASE_URL: mongodb://database:27017
  SOME_SERVICE_HOST: some-service:3000
```

I am running my Kubernetes Cluster on Google Cloud, so it will automatically create a public endpoint for my service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: gateway
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

## Issue

I have an web application that needs to make HTTP requests from the client's browser to the `gateway` service. But in order to make a request to the external service, the web app needs to know it's ip address.

So I've set up the pod, which serves the web application in a way, that it picks up an environment variable "`API_URL`" and as a result makes all HTTP requests to this url.

So I just need a way to set the `API_URL` environment variable to the public IP address of the `gateway` service to pass it into a pod when it starts.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns once you associate a dns record with your loadbalancer you can use that value as the root of `API_URL`

Comment: Ok, I may try this! But I would prefer another solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access gateway service from client's browser.

I would like to suggest you another solution that is slightly different from what you are currently trying to achieve
but it can solve your problem.

From your question I was able to deduce that your web app and gateway app are on the same cluster.

In my solution you dont need a service of type LoadBalancer and basic Ingress is enough to make it work.

You only need to create a Service object (notice that option `type: LoadBalancer` is now gone)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: gateway
spec:
selector:
  app: gateway
ports:
  - name: http
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30000
```

and you alse need an ingress object (remember that na Ingress Controller needs to be deployed to cluster in order to make it work) like one below:
More on how to deploy Nginx Ingress controller you can finde [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)
and if you are already using one (maybe different one) then you can skip this step.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: gateway-ingress
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
rules:
  - host: gateway.foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: gateway
            servicePort: 3000
```

Notice the host field.

The same you need to repeat for your web application. Remember to use appropriate host name (DNS name)
e.g. for web app: `foo.bar.com` and for gateway: `gateway.foo.bar.com`
and then just use the `gateway.foo.bar.com` dns name to connect to the gateway app from clients web browser.

You also need to create a dns entry that points `*.foo.bar.com` to Ingress's public ip address
as Ingress controller will create its own load balancer.

The flow of traffic would be like below:

```
+-------------+   +---------+   +-----------------+   +---------------------+
| Web Browser |-->| Ingress |-->| gateway Service |-->| gateway application |
+-------------+   +---------+   +-----------------+   +---------------------+
```

This approach is better becaues it won't cause issues with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in clients browser.

Examples of Ingress and Service manifests I took from official kubernetes documentation and modified slightly.

More on Ingress you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)
and on Services [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: That looks promising... I'll try it and let you know if I run into any issues later. But for now I have one question: How do I associate my domain with the Ingress? Do I just create an `A` record that points to the IP address of the Ingress?

Comment: Yes, just create an `A` record that points to the IP address of the Ingress

Comment: I've researched your suggestion by now and it really seems like a great solution. However, I am struggling with the implementation. Would you mind explaining the actual steps in more detail? :)

Comment: You might want to use GKE Ingres Controller as you are on on GKE, more info on this topic can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)
and about ingress in general in [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).
Its well documented so I think you shouldn't have any problems with it. And later just create `A` record pointing to the same ip as `EXTERNAL-IP` that is assigned to ingress's Service (kubectl get svc).

Comment: It works for me locally with `microk8s`, but I couldn't make it work on GKE. I may have to post another question about my issues

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't the exact approach you were going for, but I've found that [creating a static IP address and explicitly passing it in](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2a_using_a_service) tends to be easier to work with.

First, create a static IP address:

```
gcloud compute addresses create gke-ip --region <region>
```

where `region` is the GCP region your GKE cluster is located in.

Then you can get your new IP address with:

```
gcloud compute addresses describe gke-ip --region <region>
```

Now you can add your static IP address to your service by specifying an explicit `loadBalancerIP`.<sup>1</sup>

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: gateway
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30000
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: "1.2.3.4"
```

At this point, you can also hard-code it into your `ConfigMap` and not worry about grabbing the value from the cluster itself.

<sup>1</sup>If you've already created a `LoadBalancer` with an auto-assigned IP address, setting an IP address won't change the IP of the underlying GCP load balancer. Instead, you should delete the `LoadBalancer` service in your cluster, wait ~15 minutes for the underlying GCP resources to get cleaned up, and then recreate the `LoadBalancer` with the explicit IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The following deployment reads the external IP of a given service using `kubectl` every 10 seconds and patches a given configmap with it:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: configmap-updater
  labels:
    app: configmap-updater
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: configmap-updater
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: configmap-updater
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: configmap-updater
        image: alpine:3.10
        command: ['sh', '-c' ]
        args:
        - | #!/bin/sh
            set -x

            apk --update add curl
            curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.16.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
            chmod +x kubectl

            export CONFIGMAP="configmap/global-config"
            export SERVICE="service/gateway"

            while true
            do
                IP=`./kubectl get services $CONFIGMAP -o go-template --template='{{ (index .status.loadBalancer.ingress 0).ip }}'`
                PATCH=`printf '{"data":{"API_URL": "https://%s:3000"}}' $IP`
                echo ${PATCH}
                ./kubectl patch --type=merge -p "${PATCH}" $SERVICE

                sleep 10
            done
```

You probably have RBAC enabled in your GKE cluster and would still need to create the appropriate Role and RoleBinding for this to work correctly.

You've got a few possibilities:

- If you *really* need this to be hacked into your setup, you could use a similar approach with a sidecar container in your pod or a global service like above. Keep in mind that you would need to recreate your pods if the configmap actually changed for the changes to be picked up by the environment variables of your containers.
- Watch and query the Kubernetes-API for the external IP directly in your application, eliminating the need for an environment variable.
- Adopt your applications to not directly depend on the external IP.

Comment: That seems like a lot of effort for such a simple problem. Would you actually implement this solution yourself? Or would you use one of your other possibilities described above?

Comment: You should fix your application not to need to be aware of the load balancers external IP. Besides that I'm pretty sure this solution is the simplest possible for the given problem, regardless of the bad architecture smell.

Comment: Fixing the application would mean to establish a public DNS like api.some-domain.com?

Comment: Fixing would mean that your services does not require to know from where it is called.

Comment: The service shouldn't know from where it is called, but I need the IP of the service to make a request to it from the client application

Comment: You should use a `Service` to access your application from a client application within the cluster.

Comment: It would help if you described your *actual* problem, asking for help with your *attempted solution* might waste a lot of time - see http://xyproblem.info/ .

Comment: I agree with @SimonTesar, why do you need an IP address as opposed to simply setting up a DNS entry for your gateway and having your app use the FDQN?